# Date object SimpleDateFormat not parsing timestamp string correctly in Java (Android) environment

Tags: java, android, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I'm using the `SimpleDateFormat` object with the `Date` object as shown below. The problem lis that the `Date` object shows the wrong date, which is a few minutes off from the original string. The `Date` object appears to store the time in  total milliseconds in the debugger.

Any ideas on the problem?

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;

Date played_at_local; 

dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ");

played_at_local = dateFormat.parse("2011-04-11T22:27:18.491726-05:00"); 

//played_at_local shows "Mon Apr 11 22:35:29 America/Chicago 2011" in debugger
```

Answer (score 16):

Try removing the fractional seconds from the format string.  I just ran into the same issue, but with a slightly different format.  My input format wasn't in ISO format (no "T", and no "Z"), but the symptom was the same -- time was off by some random number of minutes and seconds, but everything else was fine.  This is what my log results looked like:

When using the fractional second format:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

# Parsed date: 2011-05-27 17:11:15.271816 => Fri May 27 17:15:46 EDT 2011
# Parsed date: 2011-05-27 17:09:37.750343 => Fri May 27 17:22:07 EDT 2011
# Parsed date: 2011-05-27 17:05:55.182921 => Fri May 27 17:08:57 EDT 2011
# Parsed date: 2011-05-27 16:55:05.69092 => Fri May 27 16:56:14 EDT 2011
# Parsed date: 2011-05-27 16:38:35.50348 => Fri May 27 16:39:25 EDT 2011
```

I fixed it by removing the fractional seconds from the format.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

# Parsed date: 2011-05-27 17:11:15.271816 => Fri May 27 17:11:15 EDT 2011
# Parsed date: 2011-05-27 17:09:37.750343 => Fri May 27 17:09:37 EDT 2011
# Parsed date: 2011-05-27 17:05:55.182921 => Fri May 27 17:05:55 EDT 2011
# Parsed date: 2011-05-27 16:55:05.69092 => Fri May 27 16:55:05 EDT 2011
# Parsed date: 2011-05-27 16:38:35.50348 => Fri May 27 16:38:35 EDT 2011
```

---

What I think is happening is that my "fractional seconds" part of the input string is too long (the same is true in the OP example).  It appears to be expecting only **three** decimal places.  If you do the math (take the first example):

- fractional seconds = 0.271816 seconds
- What DateFormat sees is `271816 / 1000` of a second
- 271816 / 1000 == 271 seconds
- 271 / 60 = 4 minutes
- 271 % 60 = 31 seconds
- 17:11:15 to 17:15:46 is exactly 4 minutes, 31 seconds off

Comment: Yes, SimpleDateFormat can't handle microseconds. The easiest thing to do is strip out the extra 3 digits, e.g. date = date.substring(0, date.length()-4)+"Z";

Comment: @scottw: except that won't always work, as you can see in my example, the last 2 items have only 5 digits, instead of 6;  so in some cases, there might be only 1 decimal place, which would be completely wrong! If you simply truncate the string to have only 3 decimal places, then it works fine as well. In our case, we didn't need the microseconds (I'd guess many people would also agree with that), so it turns out just removing the `S` from the format string is sufficient to get a usable time from it. If you do need the fractional seconds, then yeah, you have to do some string manipulation.

Comment: thats a good point Joe - my solution only worked as I was working from a service that always provided 6 digits for fractional seconds (including padding with zeroes) so I could get away with string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, working for me **Z** should be useed in date, or rmove from Format String

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");

played_at_local = dateFormat.parse("2011-04-11T22:27:18.491726Z-05:00");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three **major** problems in your code:

1. You have used `.SSSSSS` for the fraction of a second whereas the `SimpleDateFormat` does not support a precision beyond milliseconds (`.SSS`). It also means that you need to limit the digits in the fraction of a second to three.
2. You have used `Z` to parse the timezone offset, `-05:00` whereas the [correct pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this is `XXX`.
3. You have used `hh` for a time in 24-Hour format whereas the correct pattern for this is `HH`. The symbol, `hh` is used for a time in 12-Hour (i.e. with am/pm) format.

Apart from this, I recommend you always use `Locale` with a date parsing/formatting API because parts of a date-time string are represented in different ways in different `Locale`s.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse("2011-04-11T22:27:18.491-05:00");

        // Print the default string i.e. Date#toString
        System.out.println(date);

        // Print the date-time in a custom format
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-05:00"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tue Apr 12 04:27:18 BST 2011
2011-04-11T22:27:18.491-05:00
```

**Some facts about legacy date-time API:**

1. The `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it.
2. The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .

**Using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-04-11T22:27:18.491726-05:00");

        // Print the default string i.e. OffsetDateTime#toString
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Print the date-time in a custom format. Note: OffsetDateTime#toString drops
        // seconds if it is zero
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX");
        System.out.println(dtf.format(odt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-04-11T22:27:18.491726-05:00
2011-04-11T22:27:18.491726-05:00
```

**Note:** For [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), the symbol, `u` means **year** whereas the symbol, `y` means **year-of-era**. It doesn't make any difference for a year in the [AD][2] era, but it matters for a year in the BC era. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573) to learn more about it.

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`05:00 -->> 0500`

and

`hh --> HH  // error not because of this ,but date is in 24hr format.`

```
played_at_local = dateFormat.parse("2011-04-11T22:27:18.491726-05:00");
```

**should be**

```
played_at_local = dateFormat.parse("2011-04-11T22:27:18.491726-0500");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this method: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

The key thing is that fractional digits are optional and you can use a variable number of them. However, this does not seem to account for the time zone.

From the docs:

```
valueOf

public static Timestamp valueOf(String s)
Converts a String object in JDBC timestamp escape format to a Timestamp value.
Parameters:
s - timestamp in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...]. The fractional seconds may be omitted.
Returns:
corresponding Timestamp value
Throws:
IllegalArgumentException - if the given argument does not have the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
dTime  =  new  SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SS");
String  sTime =  (dTime.format(new java.util.Date())).toString();
```

Hope this help

Comment: Please add further details.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

There is no way that `SimpleDateFormat` can parse your datetime string correctly. On the other hand java.time, the modern Java date and time API, supports your format out of the box.

```
import org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime;

    String dateTimeString = "2011-04-11T22:27:18.491726-05:00";
    OffsetDateTime playedAtLocal = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeString);
    System.out.println("Parsed into " + playedAtLocal);
```

Output is:

> Parsed into 2011-04-11T22:27:18.491726-05:00

`SimpleDateFormat` only supports milliseconds, exactly three decimals on the seconds, not two, not four, not six (admittedly I’m unsure whether some Android versions have a version of `SimpleDateFormat` that can do better, but your question shows that your version cannot). `SimpleDateFormat` is also notoriously troublesome and long outdated, so you wouldn’t want to use it anyway.

java.time is so much nicer to work with. You notice that we didn’t even need an explicit formatter and thus didn’t need to write a format pattern string, which is always an error-prone task. Your date time string is in ISO 8601 format, and java.time classes parse ISO 8601 as their default.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)