# Java Unparsable date

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I have a string with the format: `String dateString = "2014-03-17T20:05:49.2300963Z"`

Trying this:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'kk:mm:ss.SSSX");
Date date = df.parse(dateString);
```

Results in an `Unparsable date` exceptioon.

The docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html indicate that `X` is used with `ISO 8601` when a single letter is used for the TimeZone.

**EDIT**
Re-reading the docs, I've switched up the `SimpleDateFormat` a little:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
dateString = dateString.replace("Z", "");
```

I take out the `Z` because I know the timezone, use `H` instead of `k` and add a couple more `S` for giggles.

Now the time is parsing, but incorrectly.  Date is accurate, Time seems to be random.

**EDIT 2**
The problem is that java only allows millisecond accuracy, so `2300963` is being interpreted as 2300 seconds and 963 milliseconds.  I'll need to format my string a little differently to get this to work.

**EDIT 3** 
Turns out you can't have a fractional part of a second in Java.  It has to be truncated to milliseconds.  I ended up using a type made available to me by my database, but the general solution is to truncate the fractional part of the second to millisecond.  I'll post example code of how to do that as an answer.

Comment: From the docs: Number: For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.

Comment: `For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.` You need to separate milliseconds from time zone.

Comment: Note that `2300963` is a weird way to put milliseconds. The `2300` will be added as minutes and seconds AFAIK.

Comment: @fge `Hour in day (1-24)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to truncate the fractional seconds to milliseconds (because Java can't handle fractional seconds):

```
public String truncate(String dateString){
  int numberOfDigits = dateString.substring(dateString.indexOf("."), dateString.length() - 1).length();

  String justMilliSecondsDate = null;
  if (numberOfDigits == 3) {
    justMicrosDate = dateString;
    } 
  else if (numberOfDigits > 3) {
    justMilliSecondsDate = dateString.substring(0, dateString.length() - numberOfDigits + 3);
  } 
  else {
      justMilliSecondsDate = dateString;
      for (int i = numberOfDigits ; i < 3 ; i++) justMilliSecondsDate += "0";
  }

  return justMilliSecondsDate;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide as many `S` as you have in your date `String`. In this case, 7

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'kk:mm:ss.SSSSSSSX");
```

This is required because, otherwise, the `DateFormat` doesn't know where the milliseconds end and where the time zone starts.

---

Note also, that

```
2300963
```

as a millisecond value means 2300 seconds and 963 milliseconds. Why do you have it that way? Why aren't those seconds part of the value in their corresponding position? When the `DateFormat` parses it, they will be added.

Comment: The 2300963 is how our partial seconds are represented. So it's a literal .2300963 of a second.  It looks like I misread the docs and we are only allowed to specify miliseconds, not partial seconds, correct?

Comment: @TylerDeWitt As far as I know, that is correct. Those are millisecond values, not fractional values.

Comment: @TylerDeWitt That's odd. You might have to do some manual parsing in that case...?

Answer (score 1):

This works: `SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'kk:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'");`

1. It's safer to specify exactly how much precision you expect (say, for milliseconds in this case). It's odd to have 7 digits but if all your dates look like this, put 7 `S`.
2. The `X` will parse a timezone of the sort `-0800`. So your string would have to look like `2014-03-17T20:05:49.2300963-0800` (or something similar). Treat the `Z` as a literal, like `T`.

**EDIT**: [Relevant to your partial seconds issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636491/date-object-simpledateformat-not-parsing-timestamp-string-correctly-in-java-and).

Comment: `Z` is not necessarily a literal. It can represent Zulu time.

Comment: True, but I meant to quote it as you would a literal. Otherwise, it is interpreted as an RFC 822 timezone.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2014-03-17T20:05:49.2300963Z" )
```

## java.time

You are using the troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

### Resolution

- Milliseconds
  The old date-time classes were limited to milliseconds resolution, for up to three digits of decimal fraction.
- Microseconds
  Your input has six digits of fractional second for microseconds.
- Nanoseconds
  The java.time classes have a resolution of nanoseconds for up to nine digits of fractional seconds. More than enough for your microseconds.

## ISO 8601

The ISO 8601 standard defines string formats to represent date-time values. You input complies with ISO 8601.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing and generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant =
    Instant.parse( "2014-03-17T20:05:49.2300963Z" );
```