# Parsing string to date: Illegal pattern character 'T'.

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat

I need to parse a string to date in java. My string has the following format:

```
2014-09-17T12:00:44.0000000Z
```

but java throws the following exception when trying to parse such format... `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'`.

Any ideas on how to parse that?

Thank you!

Comment: current_date=formatter.parse(date)

Comment: Add the formatter object also to here

Comment: yes, of course, sorry:     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS");

Comment: Use 'T' instead of only T

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Given your input of `2014-09-17T12:00:44.0000000Z`, it is not sufficient to escape the letter `T` only. You also have to handle the trailing `Z`. But be aware, this `Z` is NOT a literal, but has the meaning of `UTC+00:00` timezone offset according to `ISO-8601-standard`. So escaping `Z` is NOT correct.

`SimpleDateFormat` handles this special char `Z` by pattern symbol `X`. So the final solution looks like:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSX");
 Date d = sdf.parse("2014-09-17T12:00:44.0000000Z");
 System.out.println(d); // output: Wed Sep 17 14:00:44 CEST 2014
```

Note that the different clock time is right for timezone `CEST` (`toString()` uses system timezone), and that the result is equivalent to `UTC-time 12:00:44`. Furthermore, I had to insert seven symbols S in order to correctly process your input which pretends to have precision down to `100ns` (although Java pre 8 can only process milliseconds).

Comment: but one comment, you need to replace last X character with 'Z' in constructor SimpleDateFormat. Good solution, worked for me

Comment: @VictorPonomarenko The symbol letter X was introduced with Java 7. For Java 6, I am not sure if Z works as replacement meaning if parsed literal "Z" will be recognized as UTC+00! Maybe it is better to use the workaround for Java 6 to escape Z (interpreting it only as literal) AND to set the zone to "GMT" on the `SimpleDateFormat`-object.

Comment: on android I get runtime exception, when leave X character, but after replacement to 'Z' works good(android now works on java 7)

Comment: @VictorPonomarenko Z seems to be the right symbol for [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) although the doc is not very detailed, but keep also in mind: Android != Java (and the `SimpleDateFormat`-APIs are really different in both worlds).

Answer (score 15):

You have to escape the 'T' character:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date parse = format.parse("2014-09-17T12:00:44.0000000Z");
```

Using Answer to: [What is this date format? 2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8405125/1107536)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I don't get the same exception, but this one: "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Date"". I think the Date Format is not yet well defined...

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

It is time for the modern answer: always use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. When this question was asked, java.time had been out with Java 8 for 7 months. Today (2020) no one should use the `SimpleDateFormat` class that appears to have been the trouble in the question. It is notoriously troublesome and long outdated.

Using java.time we need no explicit formatter:

```
    String str = "2014-09-17T12:00:44.0000000Z";
    Instant i = Instant.parse(str);
    System.out.println("As Instant: " + i);
```

Output is:

> As Instant: 2014-09-17T12:00:44Z

Your format is ISO 8601 (link at the bottom). The classes of java.time generally parse ISO 8601 as their default and print ISO 8601 back from their `toString` methods. In ISO 8601 the fraction of second is optional.

If you need a `Date` object for a legacy API not yet upgraded to java.time:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(i);
    System.out.println("As old-fashioned Date: " + oldfashionedDate);
```

Output in my time zone:

> As old-fashioned Date: Wed Sep 17 14:00:44 CEST 2014

Output will vary by time zone because `Date.toString()` confusingly takes the JVM’s default time zone and uses it for rendering the string.

### What went wrong for you?

You haven’t shown us your code, but we can already tell that a couple of things are wrong:

1. `SimpleDateFormat` cannot parse a string with 7 fractional digits on the seconds correctly. It supports only milliseconds, exactly three decimals.
2. In your format pattern string you need to escape the literal `T` by enclosing it in single quotes, `'T'`, or `SimpleDateFormat` will understand it as a pattern letter, and there is no format pattern letter `T`. This is what your exception message meant.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).
- [Related question: Date object SimpleDateFormat not parsing timestamp string correctly in Java (Android) environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636491/date-object-simpledateformat-not-parsing-timestamp-string-correctly-in-java-and) about parsing more than three decimals on the seconds.
- [Related question: ISO 8601 String to Date/Time object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941357/iso-8601-string-to-date-time-object-in-android).

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        Date d = sdf.parse("2014-09-17T12:00:44.0000000Z");
        System.out.println(d); //output Wed Sep 17 12:00:44 IST 2014
    }
}
```