# LocalDateTime parsing throws "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern letter: T"

Tags: java, datetime, localdate, invocationtargetexception

The below one works:

```
LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
```

but the below item does not work.

```
LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"))
LocalDateTime.parse("2019-11-14T16:48:48.288", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
```

LocalDateTime.now() gives me date like 2019-11-13T17:12:47.494. 
I have tried parsing it and verified online a lot to fix but no luck can someone help me to understand why the parsing is throwing exception and how to fix this.

Comment: That InvocationTargetException is probably masking the real cause. If you run those two lines in isolation you should get: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern letter: T`

Comment: What do you think `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss` represents? Why?

Comment: Ya this is the error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern letter: T
i will update my Question.
Thanks for update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing string to date: Illegal pattern character 'T'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398657/parsing-string-to-date-illegal-pattern-character-t)

Comment: You don’t need a formatter in this particular case, just leave it out: `LocalDateTime.parse("2019-11-14T16:48:48.288")`. This is because your string is in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, and the classes of java.time parse this format as their default, without a formatter specified.

Comment: *LocalDateTime.now() gives me date like 2019-11-13T17:12:47.494. I have tried parsing it …* I don’t understand. You can parse a *string*. `LocalDateTime.now()` doesn’t give you a string, it gives you a `LocalDateTime`, so there is no point in parsing in, it doesn’t make sense to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add single quotes `''` around any literals:

```
LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
LocalDateTime.parse("2019-11-14T16:48:48.288", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
```

Also:

- Use `yyyy` for year.
- Use `dd` for day-of-month, instead of `DD` which is for day-of-year.
- Use `SSS` for second fractions.
- See [DateTimeFormatter Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for more information.

Comment: @DineshKumar then remove the second fraction `SSS`.

Comment: +1 Finally Fixed it by using .. 
LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));