# Java parsing String to Date returns a shifted Date

Tags: java

I got a problem when I want to parse a String to a Date.

The String looks like this **2010-11-04 00:03:50.209589**. But the result is **Thu Nov 04 00:07:19 CET 2010** where the **minutes** and **seconds** are not correct.

```
String time_input = "2010-11-04 00:03:50.209589";
SimpleDateFormat  time_now = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

Date now = time_now.parse(time_input);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I believe this has been answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636491/date-object-simpledateformat-not-parsing-timestamp-string-correctly-in-java-and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `SSSSSS` in your format string. `S` means milliseconds, so the formatter interprets `209589` as 209,589 milliseconds (3 minutes, 29 seconds, and 589 milliseconds). Add that to `00:03:50` and you'll end up with `00:07:19`.

I don't think there is a way to include microsecond precision with `DateFormat`; you can try using JodaTime or classes from the `java.time.format` package if you have Java 8.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have removed the last 3 characters from the String in order to use  `sss` format and it is working correctly.